# Need CSS transition scale to push text out of the way responsively

Tags: html, css, hover, scale, transition

I need the below code to push surrounding text out of the way.

The CSS transition currently expands and ignores the surrounding text going over it if the transition is to large. I need a good way of having the text around the transition to expand and move out of the way.

I know that it would be possible to use margin/padding and multiple a classes to get each one to push the right amount around but I was hoping for a better / more responsive option.

If any more information is needed please ask!

```css
a:link {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  display: inline-block;
}
a:hover {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<p>Check out our website and if you have a question just click the <a href="ContactUs.php">'Contact Us'</a> link and we will do our best to respond with an answer. Thank You.</p>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Like @Paulie_D said, could you elaborate a bit further?

Comment: Edited to try to make it clearer.